# How many tagged partitions of an interval are there?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

A tagged partition of an interval $[a, b] \ (a, b ∈ ℝ, a < b)$ is a finite sequence $(x_i)_{i=0}^n$ in $ℝ$, where $a=x_0 < x_1 < … < x_n = b$.

Consider the set of all tagged partitions of $[a, b]$, $M_{a,b} = \{T: T\text{ is a tagged partition of }[a, b]\}$.

Now my question is, what is the cardinality of $M_{a,b}$? If it is smaller than the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(ℝ)$, what is the cardinality of $∪_{a<b∈ℝ} M_{a,b}$?

I have been able to derive that $|ℝ| ≤ |M_{a,b}| ≤ |\mathcal{P}(ℝ)|$, where $\mathcal{P}(ℝ)$ is the power set of $ℝ$:

Proof that $|ℝ| ≤ |M_{a,b}|$: Consider the function $f: A = \{(a, x, b): a < x < b\} → (a, b), (a, x, b) \mapsto x$. $f$ is bijective, $A ⊂ M$, and $|(a,b)| = |ℝ|$.

Proof that $|M_{a,b}| ≤ |\mathcal{P}(ℝ)|$: Consider the function $f: M → A = \{B ∈ \mathcal{P}(ℝ): B ⊂ [a, b], B\text{ is finite}, a, b ∈ B\}, (x_i)_{i=0}^n \mapsto \{x_0, …, x_n\}$. $f$ is bijective, and $A ⊂ \mathcal{P}(ℝ)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $M_{a,b}$ can be regarded as a subset of $\bigcup_n \mathbb R^n$. Now $$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\def\R{\mathbb R}\R^n} = \abs{\R}, $$
hence 
$$ \abs{\bigcup_n \R^n} = \sup_n \abs{\R^n} = \sup_n \abs{\R} = \abs\R. $$

Answer (score 0):

There are $c = 2^{{\aleph}_0}$ many tagged partitions of $[a,b]\;$ when $a < b.$

There are at least $c$ many tagged partitions since each of the $c$-many real numbers $r$ such that $a < r \leq b$ gives rise to a unique tagged partiton $\{a, \, r \}.$

To see that there are at most $c$ many tagged partitions, note that all tagged partitions consisting of exactly $n$ elements (where $n \geq 2)$ is a certain subset of $[a,b]^{n},$ so the set of all tagged partitions is a subset of $\cup_{n=2}^{\infty}[a,b]^{n}.$ Since $\cup_{n=2}^{\infty}[a,b]^{n}$ is a countable union of sets each with cardinality $c,$ this union has cardinality $c,$ and hence the set of all tagged partitions (being a subset of this union) has cardinality at most $c.$